# What's wrong with this "proof" that $\frac {de^x}{dx} \neq e^x$?

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function, fake-proofs

What's wrong with this "proof" that $\frac {de^x}{dx} \neq e^x$?

$$e^x = \sum _{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}x^n $$
Therefore 
$$\frac{d e ^x}{d x}= \sum _{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{n!}x^{n-1}=  \frac{1}{(-1)!}x^{-1}+\sum _{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}x^n\neq e^x$$

The mistake must be somewhere in the fact that I pull the derivative operator "through" the sum operator. That is possible if the sum is finite, but given that it's infinite it must be invalid, but why?

Comment: @Dr.MV Is that really so important? It's clear from the context what is meant.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}$ works only for $n\neq 0$.

Comment: When $n=0$, $n/n!$ is zero, not one!

Comment: @Eff Yes, there are conventions.

Comment: $$ \frac d {dx} \,\frac{x^0}{0!} = \frac{0 x^{0-1}}{0!} =\cdots $$

Comment: @Dr. MV, I thought that the partial derivative is equivalent to the total derivative if you're taking it with respect to a function of only one variable? so isn't the $d$ and $\delta$ the same in this context, and both valid?

Comment: @Programmer2134 Partial derivatives are denoted $\frac{\partial f(\vec x)}{\partial x_i}$.  Note $\partial$ is not $\delta$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that
$$e^x = \sum _{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}x^n = \frac{1}{0!}x^0 + \sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}x^n = 1 + \sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}x^n, $$

since $0! = x^0 = 1$. Now, we can derive:

$$\frac{d e^x}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(1 + \sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}x^n\right) = \frac{d}{dx}1 +  \frac{d}{dx}\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}x^n = \\
0 + \sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{n!}x^n = \sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n!}x^{n-1} = \sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1}.$$

At this point, if you pose $m = n-1$, then you get that:

$$\frac{d e^x}{dx} = \sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1} = \sum _{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{m!}x^{m},$$

which is what you are looking for.

Comment: of course... I was mindlessly applying the derivative of a power function to $x^0$...

Comment: Besides I don't really understand what you did in your last passage, you can differentiate like that, but the first term in the differentiated sum is zero (because you get a factor $n$ multiplying the whole thing, so if $n=0$ the term is 0) and then you're left with the sum from one to infinity of the exponential series with the indexes lowered by one, then just do a change of variable and everything works

Comment: @Chris I don't catch what are you saying. Are you aware that "If $n=0$ the term is $0$" then $e^0 = 0$ (which is obviously false)??

Comment: your sum after differentiation is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n!}x^{n-1}$$, the first term, for $n=0$, is obviously 0 because of that factor $n$. Then you're left with $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n!}x^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}x^{n}$$ EDIT I just noticed that this is exactly what you did. Sorry, I'm tired.